# Feature independence in Naive Bayes example?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

"Another systemic problem with Naive Bayes is that
features are assumed to be independent. As a result,
even when words are dependent, each word contributes
evidence individually. Thus the magnitude of
the weights for classes with strong word dependencies
is larger than for classes with weak word dependencies.
To keep classes with more dependencies from dominating,
we normalize the classication weights." ([Reference](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/ICML/2003/ICML03-081.pdf) )

What does this exactly mean? Is there any example that explains it better?

Comment: You cited a whole paragraph. What exactly is unclear?

Answer (score 5):

A Naive Bayes classifier considers all features independently of each other. Basically that means that combinations of features are treated in just the same way as each feature appearing on its own.

E. g. consider the three sentences

1. "New York is a crowded city."
2. "New cars! We offer the cheapest new cars!"
3. "The new pub 'pork slaughterhouse' opened today in York."

A Naive Bayes classifier might end up assigning the label "New York" to all of these sentences. That would happen, because it observes the words "New" and "York" independently of each other. From the perspective of the classifier the first sentence contains two words indicating the label "New York" (namely "New" and "York"), the second one too ("New" and later "new") and again the third one ("new" and later "York"). It doesn't care about the second sentence missing the word "York", because two times "new" makes up for that (probably not in reality, because "new" will appear in plenty of documents that are not about New York, but for this example we just assume that both words have equal weight). The classifier will also not care about the words appearing far away from each other in the third sentence.

[image: Naive Bayes as a graphical model]

Naive Bayes can also be represented as a graphical model, as seen in the image ([source](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/papers/crf-tutorial.pdf)). Then you may view y as the category "New York" and x1...x4 as the observable features "New", "York", "Big", "Apple". Notice that there are connections from y to x1...x4, but not between each of the x's.

The second part of the paragraph that you posted seems to be about weight normalization. Basically if you have documents about the categories "Tokyo" and "Los Angeles" and you assume that the names of those cities are observations pointing with equal weights towards the respective category, then a document that only contains the words

> Tokyo Los Angeles

would be classified by your Naive Bayes classifier as belonging to the category "Los Angeles". That's because there are two observations in favor of that category ("Los", "Angeles"), but only one in favor of Tokyo ("Tokyo"). Therefor you will need some way of normalizing your weights to accommodate for that problem.

Comment: `might end up assigning the label "New York" to all of these sentences`There's no `York` on the second sentence

Comment: Yes, but if you would count `New` only if also `York` is observed, then the feature `New` would depend on `York`. In Naive Bayes, all features are viewed as conditionally independent of each other. Therefor `P("New"|<category:New York>) = P("New"|<category:New York>, "York")`. So you can classify a document as `about New York` even if the word `York` never appears in it. (Similarly, there might be hundreds of other words representing `New York` that also don't have to appear in the document.)